# $f = g$ a.e., $f$ is measurable, $g$ is not

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose ($X,\cal M, \mu$) is not complete. Let $E$ be a subset of a set of
>   measure zero that does not belong to $\cal M$. Let $f=0$ on $X$ and $g=\chi
>  _E$. Show that $f=g$ a.e. on $X$ while $f$ is measurable and $g$ is not.

I understand that if $(X,\cal M, \mu)$ IS complete and $f=g$ a.e., then $f, g$ are measurable.

But, for this, since $f=0$ and $g=\chi _E$ = $0$ when $x \in E$, then how do we show that $f=g$ a.e. for $x \notin E$? Obviously, we must use $g$ not being measurable.

Comment: You write "$g=\chi _E$ = $0$ when $x \in E$" but it's "$g=\chi _E$ = $0$ when $x \not\in E$". Maybe that clears it up a bit

Comment: Ah, thanks. Is Marek's answer satisfactory? He shows f = g a.e. given f measurable and g not. It seems as if there should be more.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me you are having a trivial confusion about the definition of almost everywhere. In the problem, $E$ is supposed to be a subset of a set of measure zero, say $A$. Now, $f - g$ is certainly zero on $M \setminus A \subset M \setminus E$ and therefore zero a.e, so $f = g$ a.e.

Comment: You are right, I recall that now. So, how would the measurability of f and g affect our outcome?

Comment: @Jake: I am not sure I understand your question. This doesn't affect the outcome, it _is_ the outcome. The point of the exercise is to conclude that the functions are the same almost everywhere and that this is compatible with one being measurable and the other not and thus give you some intuition about incomplete measure spaces.

Comment: You might take the following proposition from this exercise: "If there exist $f$, $g$ that are equal almost everywhere and one of them is measurable while the other is not then the measure space is necessarily incomplete."